# How does RTCPeerConnection use the array of STUN/TURN servers?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun

We are doing some research regarding the behavior of Web RTC with the list of STUN/TURN servers provided. I cannot find any documentation so I am doing some tests but I hope someone can provide a clear explanation.

Following the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/urls) we can provide any number of servers.

- But how does the RTCPeerConnection choose the server to use?
- Does it try the first one and if it fails try the second one until one works?
- Should all the servers be up and running or is the connection able to skip an unreachable server?
- If the first server is able to conclude the negociation, does it still try with the remaining servers?
- Does it simply change the list of candidates?

To provide more context, we have a working WebRTC application using the Google Stun Servers (`stun.l.google.com:19302`) however we are migrating on our own STUN servers. We have an API that returns the list of STUN servers to use however based on the behavior we might provide a different list.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how does the RTCPeerConnection choose the server to use?

The RTCPeerConnection doesn't choose a server it choose a pair of ICE candidates. A ICE candidate is generated by contacting the servers.

> Does it try the first one and if it fails try the second one until one works?

It contacts them all (this process is called gathering). Your WebRTC implementation *may* stop gathering when a connection is established.

> Should all the servers be up and running or is the connection able to skip an unreachable server?

It is ok for a server to be down. Trickle ICE allows connectivity checks to proceed if all of them are not working.

> If the first server is able to conclude the negociation, does it still try with the remaining servers?

Two WebRTC Agents don't communicate through a STUN server, this question has a little more nuance. In the [connectivity](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/#ice) chapter of WebRTC for the Curious check out how ICE goes through steps.

> Does it simply change the list of candidates?

Yea! For each STUN server you *may* have another candidate. This depends on the behavior of your NAT. You could be behind a NAT configuration that only gives you one mapping. Unlikely but still possible!

Comment: Alright, that's what I had in mind, thanks a lot for your explanation. It answers all my questions so I tag it as answered